# How can Amazon Aurora gain higher read-only throughput?

Tags: distributed-systems, databases

I read the [Amazon Aurora paper](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eyxy/cs764-f20/papers/aurora-sigmod-17.pdf) and in the performance result section (i.e. 6.1.1), it says

> The results are shown in Figure 7 and Figure 6, and measure the
> performance in terms of write and read statements per second
> respectively. Aurora’s performance doubles for each higher
> instance size and for the r3.8xlarge achieves 121,000 writes/sec
> and 600,000 reads/sec which is 5x that of MySQL 5.7 which tops
> out at 20,000 reads/sec and 125,000 writes/sec.

The gain of write-only throughput makes total sense to me as Aurora eliminates a lot of synchronous writes and network I/Os required but the read throughput confuses me.

In the case of read-only, Aurora would still have to go fetch the pages from the storage tier which to my understanding could potentially have unprocessed logs since they are materialized periodically. So if anything, it should be slightly slower?

What could be the explanation for this read-only throughput gain of Aurora?